# My html cant find my linked javascript event though its in the correct directory, very stumped here

Tags: node.js, express, scripting, tags, syntax-error

where I link index.js

```
<script src="/assets/js/index.js"></script>
```

Folder Directory is such
assests
-css
--style.css
-js
--index.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bErfF.png)

Error Im getting

```
index.html:25 GET file:///assets/js/index.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

Comment: refer to picture above for folder structure

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using an express app(by the tag in question). The static resources such as your javascript, css, images, etc. should be inside the public folder which gets served on running the application. Could you try **moving the assets folder inside the public folder and then have a script tag pointing to that resource**.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps to remove the first slash:

```
<script src="assets/js/index.js"></script>
```

Or startend with a dot

```
<script src="./assets/js/index.js"></script>
```